# Which free notetaking software allows me to highlight specified words, categorize ideas and organize weblinks?

Tags: linux, open-source, note-taking, knowledge-organization, debian

I'm looking for free and open source notetaking software that allows me to highlight specified words (or preferably whole lines after a specified word) and helps me organize and categorize ideas and similar textual content?

It would be great if that same software could also help me organize weblinks and associated content. But maybe that's more or less a separate question / software.

Under Windows Notepad++ [allowed me to create a custom language to highlight words](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages).

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try those one:

- ## [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/)

  It's available for almost ALL platform,

> Turtl lets you take notes, bookmark websites, and store documents for
>   sensitive projects. From sharing passwords with your coworkers to
>   tracking research on an article you're writing, Turtl keeps it all
>   safe from everyone but you and those you share with.

It has  bookmarking extensions for your browser that makes it easy to bookmark the current page you're on. This is great for *quickly* saving sites to read later or for creating a list of pages you frequently visit.

---

## - [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/)

[image]

You can check more [screenshots here](http://zim-wiki.org/screenshots.html)

---

## - [LeaNote](https://github.com/leanote/leanote)

It's open source apparently.

---

## - [Boostnote](https://boostnote.io/)

---

**edit**

## - [QOwnNotes](http://www.qownnotes.org/)

QOwnNotes Is another option too

[image: QOwnNotes]

---

**edit 2**

## - [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)

[Area51 link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105326/tiddlywiki)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Org mode](http://org-mode.org), which runs on top of Emacs, has lots of features for taking, categorizing, and organizing notes. Emacs itself has a generic highlighting feature: type `M-x regexp-highlight RET`, then the regular expression you want to highlight. For example, the regular expression `cheese.+` highlights the word `cheese` and everything after it on the same line.

Comment: Good suggestion. However I'd like to use a GUI.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm Emacs has a GUI, which most people use these days. You can run it in a terminal, but there's no real reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/) could be one more software to have a look at.

- is free and open source,
- although it can be considered primarily as a to-do list software, I think it fits very well to your use case,
- you can tag, highlight, organize and categorize your notes,
- it does run on Linux/Debian machines, although a bit of [tweaking is required](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=linux),
- and you can organize web links and associated context no problem.

Here is a quick screenshot:
[image]

I think this is a really cool software, maybe it is worth a look.