# Open source markdown editor with file tree panel

Tags: linux, open-source, text-editor, markdown, editor

I'm searching for an editor to work with my notes organized as a hierarchical file tree in a markdown format. It should display both file tree and text editor panels like that:

```
+================================================+
||  notes                 ||  Text editor area  ||
||  ├── cooking           ||                    ||
||  ├── personal          ||                    ||
||  │   ├── bookmarks.md  ||                    ||
||  │   └── random.md     ||                    ||
||  └── projects          ||                    ||
+================================================+
```

It should:

1. display simultaneously file tree and editor area (and be able to switch between files);
2. support markdown format (highlight markdown format and display formatted preview);
3. (nice to have) be able to display TOC generated from markdown headers in file;
4. be open source and work under Linux.

There are lots of markdown editors for Linux but they all lacking file tree panel for quick access to all files under working directory.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! You might wish to take a look at the answers to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45247/185). Especially the screenshots of ZIM and QOwnNotes might catch your eye – with the latter mostly fitting your requirements (just not sure about TOC).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VScodium](https://vscodium.com), the telemetry/tracking-free version of [Visual Studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (which itself claims to be opensource but the matter is debated). Both software provides :

- Filesystem view, in the *Explorer* panel,
- Markdown syntax highlighting,
- Markdown document hierarchy view in the *Explorer* panel, *Outline* subpanel
- Markdown preview.

Specific extensions of interest could be:

- [markdown-all-in-one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) for several features (including TOC),
- [auto-markdown-TOC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=huntertran.auto-markdown-toc) specifically to generate TOC,
- [markdownlink](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint) to enforce quality and consistency of your markdown files.
- [vale](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=errata-ai.vale-server) to enforce style guidelines.

Both should run on Windows/Linux. They may not be exactly "lightweight" software.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

https://www.zettlr.com/

display simultaneously file tree and editor area (and be able to switch between files); CHECK

support markdown format (highlight markdown format and display formatted preview); CHECK

(nice to have) be able to display TOC generated from markdown headers in file; CHECK

be open source and work under Linux. CHECK